# How can I maintain the relationship between two table on delete and on update?

Tags: database, xampp

`purchases` (`p_id`, `s_name`, `invoice_number`, `purchase_date`, `total`)
`suppliers` (`s_id`, `s_name`, `s_email`, `s_number`, `s_address`)

These are the two table, linked with s_name, there is some data in both and if I delete one row in suppliers, I want that s_name value to stay in purchases (without replace by null or on delete cascade). And I need on update cascade there so that all the s_name on purchases changes with change in suppliers s_name.

I tried removing the foreign key, if I remove the foreign key then I won't be able to update all the s_name in purchases table if s_name on suppliers table is updated.

I also tried using on update cascade only, it works fine for update, but while trying to delete on suppliers table it doesn't allow me to delete.